# How do I show relationships in Enterprise Architect

Tags: uml, case, relationship, diagram, enterprise-architect

I have used Enterprise Architect to create a simple class diagram. What I can't figure out how to do is make it show the relationships such as 1 to 1, etc...

Seems like a simple thing to show, but this program is not user friendly at all.

Comment: did you manage to link to classes with an association? You might want to double click that relation and modify the cardinality.

Comment: I do have the classes linked with associations. When I double click the association, I don't see anything that has to do with cardinality. I only see cardinality when I double click the class itself. Cardinality is listed under the details section there.

Answer (score 10):

It is fairly simple actually - for both Class and Object diagrams you can use "Associate" from the toolbox. Then if you double click the association, you will be able to enter multiplicity under "Source Role" and "Target Role" tabs.

Comment: I guess I should have added some info. I created the class model by reverse engineering java code. I had to take the jpeg (class model) from EA and add all the missing info myself in Photoshop. I'm not sure I've gotten it all right and that's why I wanted EA to do it for me.

Comment: Using the Association from the toolbox just adds a new association to the model. I wanted the existing relationships to show (1.1, 1.*, etc...)

Comment: What is the kind of existing relationship?

Comment: @neveser Please update your original question with this extra information. Reverse engineering only adds associations in certain circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

When you draw two classes and put association connector between them, you should right click the association, you will see multiplicity, but you should do this work in near of any class on the line of association.

Answer (score 0):

In the association properties dialog go to target and source role sections. 
There you'll find the multiplicity fields to fill in.
You can also right click near the ends of the association on a diagram and select "multiplicity" from the context menu.